# How to assign IP address for MS SQL AG Listener?

Tags: networking, sql-server, failovercluster

Sorry folks this is maybe a stupid question but I'm struggling.
All manuals like [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sql-server-always-on-availability-group-ag-listener-step-by-step-guide) just say "Click to add to add a static IP address to a selected subnet..." and nothing more.

I don't understand what sort of the address should it be.

(1) Is it just unoccupied, available address in a subnet? So, listener is like a "device" connected internally to my network? But then how does it magically find correct route to which gateway, if I cannot specify one? Does it add itself to server routing table?

-OR-

(2) I need first to attach the address to some LAN interface on the server. It sounds more logical. But why do I have then to specify subnet mask in the wizard, if IP interface is managed by OS?

So far I tried both ways. No errors in either way, created successfully. (1) looks more like should it be and *safer* but I can't ping it, can't connect to it, so I assume it just does not work. Tried to restart SQL service, no joy.

How do you do this?

UPDATE: This is a read-scale AG without cluster. The reason why I want to use listener is rare specific connections errors from Net Core app, and it seems like listener should help in this particular setup.

UPDATE2: Guy in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWYmbZBheyk on 18:42 insists it should be just local IP, i.e. (2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using PowerShell with a few lines of code. Open PowerShell on of the nodes in your cluster

Adjust the values to your environment they start with Your and Network Name

```
Import-Module FailoverClusters
$agListener = Get-ClusterResource -Name "YourAGListenerName"
$agListener | Set-ClusterParameter -Name HostRecordTTL -Value 300
$agListener | Set-ClusterParameter -Name DnsTtl -Value 300
$agListener | Set-ClusterParameter -Name RegisterAllProvidersIP -Value 0
$agListener | Set-ClusterParameter -Name Network -Value "YourNetworkName"
$agListener | Set-ClusterParameter -Name Address -Value "YourDesiredIPAddress"
Get-ClusterResource | where { $_.ResourceType -eq "Network Name" } | Update-ClusterResource
```

Comment: I use read-scale availability group without cluster

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer. In a cluster environment, creating a listener creates a network resource (this one that causes adding a listener to AD as a computer). WSFC takes care of that. This network resource must be a representation of actual network listener.

In the read-scale AG it seems like we have to create IP manually, so (1) is correct, and we don't need all this stuff with AD.